# How to access profile object(profile id) in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a view that I set up that allows me to view all the training for a specific employee profile:

```
class ManageTrainingView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    model = Training
    template_name = 'ppm/training.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    #  Get training queryset for specific profile id
    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Training.objects.filter(profile_id=pk)
```

The problem I'm have is that I'm trying to add more training for a specific employee profile using a profile id instead of a user id. In my training.html template this Works

training.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'ppm:add-training' user.id %}">Add Training</a></li>
```

But this doesn't(NoReverseMatch)

```
<li><a href="{% url 'ppm:add-training' profile.id %}">Add Training</a></li>
```

So my question is what do I need to do in order to add training for a specific employee profile instead of a user? How do I access the profile object that I'm currently on in the template so that profile.id will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and I think this is it. If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

What I did was override get_context_data to return the profile id to the template.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    context = super(ManageTrainingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile_id'] = pk
    return context
```

Now I am able to use:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'ppm:add-training' profile_id %}">Add Training</a></li>
```